# Does mass transit azure function support saga state machine orchestration?

Tags: masstransit

I am using AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions for azure function sb trigger . can I add mass transit Saga orchestration/state machine to the azure function app? is that compatible ? Any sample GitHub app would be helpful. Thanks !

Not able to configure .

Answer (score 0):

The `IMessageReceiver` has `HandleConsumer`, `HandleSaga`, and `HandleExecuteActivity` methods on it which can be used for any of those consumer types. You can add the saga using `AddSagaStateMachine` when configuring MassTransit, and dispatch messages to the saga from within functions the same as you would with a consumer.

The [`HandleConsumer`](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction/blob/master/src/Sample.AzureFunction/SubmitOrderFunctions.cs#L23) method is shown in the example. The same syntax is used for sagas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris ! One follow up question is - I can send initial Submit Order with Handle Saga , But how can I send different types of message ? as I can not modify/frame ServiceBusReceivedMessage to send different type of message in the SB triggered call .

Comment: The message type is either defined in the message by MassTransit sending the message, or you'd need to use separate queues for each message type. There has to be a way to distinguish the type or MassTransit doesn't know how to handle it.